# Laravel Many to Many query relationship with where clause

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

**Problem**

I want to make use of eloquent rather than relying in joins

**Queries**

```
$relationship = DB::table('tournament_user')
        ->join('tournaments','tournament_user.tournament_id' , '=', 'tournaments.id')
        ->join('users', 'tournament_user.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select('tournament_user.user_id','tournament_user.tournament_id')
        ->where('tournament_user.user_id','=',$request->user()->id)
        ->get();
```

This query returns list of all tournaments id for a loggedin user.

How can I avoid joins?

I tried this : `$relations = User::with('tournaments')->where('id',$request->user()->id)->get();`

It returns only one row. whereas there are 3 tournaments that belong to user with id = 2.

I want to simply convert the above Joins query to use eloquent model.

**User Model**

```
public function tournaments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tournament', 'tournament_user','tournament_id','user_id');
}
```

**Tournament Model**

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\User','tournament_user','tournament_id','user_id');
}
```

**Var_Dump**

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#350 (1){  
   [  
      "items":protected
   ]   => array(1)   {  
      [  
         0
      ]      => object(App\User)#345 (23)      {  
         [  
            "table":protected
         ]         => string(5) "users"         [  
            "fillable":protected
         ]         => array(5)         {  
            [  
               0
            ]            => string(4) "name"            [  
               1
            ]            => string(5) "email"            [  
               2
            ]            => string(3) "dob"            [  
               3
            ]            => string(6) "gender"            [  
               4
            ]            => string(8) "password"
         }         [  
            "hidden":protected
         ]         => array(2)         {  
            [  
               0
            ]            => string(8) "password"            [  
               1
            ]            => string(14) "remember_token"
         }         [  
            "connection":protected
         ]         => NULL         [  
            "primaryKey":protected
         ]         => string(2) "id"         [  
            "perPage":protected
         ]         => int(15)         [  
            "incrementing"
         ]         => bool(true)         [  
            "timestamps"
         ]         => bool(true)         [  
            "attributes":protected
         ]         => array(12)         {  
            [  
               "id"
            ]            => int(2)            [  
               "name"
            ]            => string(4) "john"            [  
               "email"
            ]            => string(14) "john@gmail.com"            [  
               "role"
            ]            => string(4) "user"            [  
               "gender"
            ]            => string(4) "male"            [  
               "status"
            ]            => string(6) "active"            [  
               "dob"
            ]            => string(10) "2001-01-01"            [  
               "password"
            ]            => string(60) "$2y$10$QCtSuNroLftEm.xFLiAbheCt32dSp24rXfn9aJX8pvfbVNVMKyZ.6"            [  
               "remember_token"
            ]            => string(60) "3CPQZ1GSFjTV4qBkCoxt30fOSMrKHsPCkgeMb3uJwKz2nyKUqsDABizIVssH"            [  
               "created_at"
            ]            => string(19) "2016-03-16 10:49:29            " ["            updated_at"
         ]         => string(19) "2016-07-23 10:49:35         " ["         image"
      ]      => string(13) "/img/user.png"
   }   [  
      "original":protected
   ]   => array(12)   {  
      [  
         "id"
      ]      => int(2)      [  
         "name"
      ]      => string(4) "john"      [  
         "email"
      ]      => string(14) "john@gmail.com"      [  
         "role"
      ]      => string(4) "user"      [  
         "gender"
      ]      => string(4) "male"      [  
         "status"
      ]      => string(6) "active"      [  
         "dob"
      ]      => string(10) "2001-01-01"      [  
         "password"
      ]      => string(60) "$2y$10$QCtSuNroLftEm.xFLiAbheCt32dSp24rXfn9aJX8pvfbVNVMKyZ.6"      [  
         "remember_token"
      ]      => string(60) "3CPQZ1GSFjTV4qBkCoxt30fOSMrKHsPCkgeMb3uJwKz2nyKUqsDABizIVssH"      [  
         "created_at"
      ]      => string(19) "2016-03-16 10:49:29      " ["      updated_at"
   ]   => string(19) "2016-07-23 10:49:35   " ["   image"
]=> string(13) "/img/user.png"
}[  
"relations":protected
]=> array(1){  
[  
   "tournaments"
]=> object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#353 (1){  
   [  
      "items":protected
   ]   => array(1)   {  
      [  
         0
      ]      => object(App\Tournament)#352 (23)      {  
         [  
            "table":protected
         ]         => string(11) "tournaments"         [  
            "fillable":protected
         ]         => array(7)         {  
            [  
               0
            ]            => string(6) "t_name"            [  
               1
            ]            => string(6) "t_desc"            [  
               2
            ]            => string(6) "t_club"            [  
               3
            ]            => string(10) "t_location"            [  
               4
            ]            => string(6) "t_date"            [  
               5
            ]            => string(11) "t_starttime"            [  
               6
            ]            => string(9) "t_endtime"
         }         [  
            "connection":protected
         ]         => NULL         [  
            "primaryKey":protected
         ]         => string(2) "id"         [  
            "perPage":protected
         ]         => int(15)         [  
            "incrementing"
         ]         => bool(true)         [  
            "timestamps"
         ]         => bool(true)         [  
            "attributes":protected
         ]         => array(12)         {  
            [  
               "id"
            ]            => int(2)            [  
               "t_name"
            ]            => string(22) "Flag Stroke Play Event"            [  
               "t_desc"
            ]            => string(499) "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters,
            as opposed to using 'Content here. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
            when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."            [  
               "t_club"
            ]            => string(21) "Hermitage golf course"            [  
               "t_location"
            ]            => string(7) "Sharjah"            [  
               "t_date"
            ]            => string(10) "2016-07-20"            [  
               "t_starttime"
            ]            => string(8) "10:00:00            " ["            t_endtime"
         ]         => string(8) "01:00:00         " ["         lat"
      ]      => float(25.2)      [  
         "lng"
      ]      => float(55.27)      [  
         "created_at"
      ]      => string(19) "2016-02-22 16:00:00      " ["      updated_at"
   ]   => string(19) "2016-06-07 12:36:06   " } ["   original":protected
]=> array(14){  
   [  
      "id"
   ]   => int(2)   [  
      "t_name"
   ]   => string(22) "Flag Stroke Play Event"   [  
      "t_desc"
   ]   => string(499) "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters,
   as opposed to using 'Content here. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
   when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book."   [  
      "t_club"
   ]   => string(21) "Hermitage golf course"   [  
      "t_location"
   ]   => string(7) "Sharjah"   [  
      "t_date"
   ]   => string(10) "2016-07-20"   [  
      "t_starttime"
   ]   => string(8) "10:00:00   " ["   t_endtime"
]=> string(8) "01:00:00" ["lat"
]=> float(25.2)[  
"lng"
]=> float(55.27)[  
"created_at"
]=> string(19) "2016-02-22 16:00:00" ["updated_at"
]=> string(19) "2016-06-07 12:36:06" ["pivot_tournament_id"
]=> int(2)[  
"pivot_user_id"
]=> int(2)
}[  
"relations":protected
]=> array(1){  
[  
"pivot"
]=> object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Pivot)#351 (26){  
[  
"parent":protected
]=> object(App\User)#331 (23){  
[  
"table":protected
]=> string(5) "users"[  
"fillable":protected
]=> array(5){  
[  
   0
]=> string(4) "name"[  
   1
]=> string(5) "email"[  
   2
]=> string(3) "dob"[  
   3
]=> string(6) "gender"[  
   4
]=> string(8) "password"
}[  
"hidden":protected
]=> array(2){  
[  
   0
]=> string(8) "password"[  
   1
]=> string(14) "remember_token"
}[  
"connection":protected
]=> NULL[  
"primaryKey":protected
]=> string(2) "id"[  
"perPage":protected
]=> int(15)[  
"incrementing"
]=> bool(true)[  
"timestamps"
]=> bool(true)[  
"attributes":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"original":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"relations":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"visible":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"appends":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"guarded":protected
]=> array(1){  
[  
   0
]=> string(1) "*"
}[  
"dates":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"dateFormat":protected
]=> NULL[  
"casts":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"touches":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"observables":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"with":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"morphClass":protected
]=> NULL[  
"exists"
]=> bool(false)[  
"wasRecentlyCreated"
]=> bool(false)
}[  
"foreignKey":protected
]=> string(13) "tournament_id"[  
"otherKey":protected
]=> string(7) "user_id"[  
"guarded":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"connection":protected
]=> NULL[  
"table":protected
]=> string(15) "tournament_user"[  
"primaryKey":protected
]=> string(2) "id"[  
"perPage":protected
]=> int(15)[  
"incrementing"
]=> bool(true)[  
"timestamps"
]=> bool(false)[  
"attributes":protected
]=> array(2){  
[  
"tournament_id"
]=> int(2)[  
"user_id"
]=> int(2)
}[  
"original":protected
]=> array(2){  
[  
"tournament_id"
]=> int(2)[  
"user_id"
]=> int(2)
}[  
"relations":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"hidden":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"visible":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"appends":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"fillable":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"dates":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"dateFormat":protected
]=> NULL[  
"casts":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"touches":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"observables":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"with":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"morphClass":protected
]=> NULL[  
"exists"
]=> bool(true)[  
"wasRecentlyCreated"
]=> bool(false)
}
}[  
"hidden":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"visible":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"appends":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"guarded":protected
]=> array(1){  
[  
0
]=> string(1) "*"
}[  
"dates":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"dateFormat":protected
]=> NULL[  
"casts":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"touches":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"observables":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"with":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"morphClass":protected
]=> NULL[  
"exists"
]=> bool(true)[  
"wasRecentlyCreated"
]=> bool(false)
}
}
}
}[  
"visible":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"appends":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"guarded":protected
]=> array(1){  
[  
0
]=> string(1) "*"
}[  
"dates":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"dateFormat":protected
]=> NULL[  
"casts":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"touches":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"observables":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"with":protected
]=> array(0){  

}[  
"morphClass":protected
]=> NULL[  
"exists"
]=> bool(true)[  
"wasRecentlyCreated"
]=> bool(false)
}
}
}
```

Comment: can you var_dump your result? this query should return 1 user and that user object will have a tournaments object that should contain related results.

Comment: I have added var_dump. please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your relationships in model is wrong.

Your Relationship

```
public function tournaments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tournament', 'tournament_user','tournament_id','user_id');
}
```

But as per Laravel [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many),

> The third argument is the foreign key name of the model on which you
>   are defining the relationship, while the fourth argument is the
>   foreign key name of the model that you are joining to:

Which mean your relationship in **User Model** should be like

```
public function tournaments()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Tournament', 'tournament_user', 'user_id', 'tournament_id');
}
```

Comment: I was confused with the thought that, the arguments might also need chronological order. You are right about it. I didn't get right result for query: $user = User::with('tournaments')->get(); simply. I just checked my database and relationship was wrong.

Answer (score 2):

It looks correct for a many-to-many relationship.

The following should give you all the `users` and then for each user it returns the tournaments using eager loading on the tournaments relationship.

```php
$users = User::with('tournaments')->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    foreach ($user->tournaments as $tournament) {
        // Do what you want todo with the tournament
    }
}
```

Then for your case it will return a single user with its tournaments.

```php
$user = User::with('tournaments')->where('id', $request->user()->id)->get();
foreach ($user->tournaments as $tournament) {
    // Do what you want todo with the tournament
}
```